# Apply a class name to a Array of Html Nodes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to apply a class to a array of HTML Nodes like:

```
 var divRelatedBox = document.getElementsByClassName('related-box');
 divRelatedBox.classList.toggle('hide')
```

But it's not working...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Important note:   `document.getElementsByClassName` is *NOT* an array, although it is array-like in the sense it has numeric indexes and a length property  It is  `Node List`, and if memory serves me correctly, a `Live Node List`.

Comment: What do you want it to do? What's the problem?

Comment: I was trying to apply a class to multiples html elements with class `related-box` @towerofnix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be confused by jQuery. Contrary to jQuery objects, you can't apply [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) methods directly on an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and have it apply to every element in the list. You have to loop through the list and apply your methods one by one.

```
var divRelatedBox = document.getElementsByClassName('related-box');

for (var i = 0; i < divRelatedBox.length; i++) {
    divRelatedBox[i].classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

Or using [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which I find cleaner:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divRelatedBox, function (element) {
    element.classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

Comment: What about ECMA2016? `for (let e of Array.from(els)) ...` :)